# How to handle .tar.md5 files

Tags: android, tar, checksum

I was wondering about how to create / extract / verify `.tar.md5` files. These files are used when flashing images to android devices, see [here](http://donandroid.com/odin-tutorial-how-to-use-odin-to-flash-rom-on-android-device-634) for example.

As far as I can tell the checksum is appended to the file like this:

```
cp file.tar file.tar.md5
md5sum file.tar >> file.tar.md5
```

Firstly I would like to know how to extract the file. Can I simply use `tar -xf` on the `file.tar.md5`?

How can I verify the integrity of the file? I would like to remove the last bytes (containing the checksum) from the file to obtain the original file back. I guess you would have to use a regexp to match the `checksum  file.tar`? Is something like this implemented somewhere already?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  The hash files that accompany tarballs and other large files typically contain *only* the hash, not a copy of the original file.

Comment: To put it another way, the file type is not `.tar.md5`, it's just `.md5`.  `file.tar` identifies which file it's a hash of.

Comment: I would have thought that as well, but that just isn't true:

file file.tar.md5 => file.tar.md5: POSIX tar archive (GNU)

Comment: Also: the series of commands is shown here: https://youtu.be/JBcbd-Xfkg8?t=1m47s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all tar -xf should work since tar continues while it matches its' packing algorithm. If the file stops matching so would tar.
Also most archive managers such as 7-zip or winrar will open it if you remove the ".md5".
They might print error regarding mismatch with the end of the file, ignore it.

As for verifying the file:

- **print out the stored md5sum:** tail -z -n 1 [File name here].tar.md5
- **calculate the md5sum of the tar part of the file:** head -z -n -1 [File name here].tar.md5 | md5sum

Comment: Thanks, I was unsure regarding how to use the tail command in this case:)

Answer (score 2):

What works for me with Ubuntu 19.10 is:

- download single-file 4 GiB zip from sammobile com
- unzip to several *.tar.md5
- run the below command-line

.

```
for F in *.tar.md5; do echo -n "$F " &&
  EXP=($(tail --lines=1 "$F")) &&
  ACT=($(head --lines=-1 "$F" | md5sum)) &&
  if [ ${EXP[0]} = ${ACT[0]} ]; then echo -n "md5ok " &&
  tar --extract --file "$F" && echo "done" 
  else echo "FAIL"; fi; done &&
unlz4 --multiple --verbose *.lz4
AP_G965U1UEU3ARL1_CL14745140_QB21029084_REV01_user_low_ship_MULTI_CERT_meta.tar.md5 md5ok done
BL_G965U1UEU3ARL1_CL14745140_QB21029084_REV01_user_low_ship_MULTI_CERT.tar.md5 md5ok done
CP_G965U1UEU3ARL1_CP11407818_CL14745140_QB21029084_REV01_user_low_ship_MULTI_CERT.tar.md5 md5ok done
CSC_OMC_OYM_G965U1OYM3ARL1_CL14745140_QB21029084_REV01_user_low_ship_MULTI_CERT.tar.md5 md5ok done
HOME_CSC_OMC_OYM_G965U1OYM3ARL1_CL14745140_QB21029084_REV01_user_low_ship_MULTI_CERT.tar.md5 md5ok done
…
```

But we should all try to get away from bash